# How this site generate hash of my file without uploading it?

Tags: javascript, hash

I wonder how [this](http://onlinemd5.com/) site generate hash value of my files without uploading them? I mean I drag and drop a huge file in a frame in this site and only a few seconds later, it returns its hash value! (With my internet speed I need hours to upload it!).

First site view:

[image]

Note that I compare its output with [this](http://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator) site that need to upload the file to calculate its hash value, and both have equal output!

Second site view:

[image]

Does it use any local program to calculate the hash value(using javascript for example)? If so, why all the online tools doesn't implement this fast method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you drop a file onto the browser window (In a drag and drop enabled zone) you're essentially performing the same function as clicking a "Select File" button, navigating to a file and selecting it. This will make the binary data of the file along with some meta information available to the browser.

This data is generally used to upload to the server. It can also be used to generate thumbnails of images, for instance. In this case, they are performing a hash function against the data in the browser. They don't need to upload it to the server to do so.